# Retrieve data from inner document embedded in array

Tags: arrays, spring, mongodb

How do I retrieve data from inner document embedded in array in MongoDB using Spring?

```
{
    "project" : "proj001",
    "sourcevo" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "HpAlm",
            "type" : "database",
            "source" : "mysql",
            "toolvo" : {
                "url" : "https://123.com",
                "userName" : "123user",
                "password" : "password"
            },
            "dbvo" : {
                "servername" : "",
                "userName" : "",
                "password" : ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: By `using Spring`, did you mean MongoTemplate?

Comment: yes. I want to retrieve the data for name="HpAlm"

Answer (score 0):

Using the MongoDB `db.collection.find()` method, the query below would return all documents where the **sourcevo** array contains an element whose **name** field is equal to "HpAlm".

```
db.collection.find("{ sourcevo.name : { $eq : 'HpAlm' } }");
```

In MongoTemplate, the query should look something like the following:

```
BasicQuery myQuery = new BasicQuery("{ sourcevo.name : { $eq : 'HpAlm' } }");
List<Document> docsList = mongoOperation.find(myQuery, Document.class);
```